# Stack overflow BETA Navigation Testing - Will Android Enthusiasts do the same?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) they are trying out a new navigation bar (you have to opt in to try it out).

**My Question is:** Will [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) be following suit after [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) gets there new navigation bar working? Will the people on here be able to adopt the new look of the navigation bar as well in the near future?

**Link:** [New Navigation Release Candidate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate?cb=1)

---

I for one would like Android Enthusiasts to adopt this once it is finished, if they are allowed to use the code. What are your thoughts on this if Android Enthusiasts were allowed uses of the new navigation bar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites are manned by the same company, and are run by essentially the same engine, with some additional per-site customizations like MathJax, etc. The new navigation is coming to all of them; this isn't really a subject for discussion.

New interface is being tested on SO first, since the guiding principle of the company is to figure out what developers need, and then provide that thing to others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Just what I wanted to know.

Comment: This is correct. One of the things we're working on solving for Stack Overflow first is a traffic challenge given the amount of questions, tags, and users on that site. Once we're done, we'll gauge how well the solution scales to all the community sites. It's possible we iterate for different use cases.

Comment: I just ran across this again and realized that Kurtis never got a diamond on this site, so, for those who don't know, he is an employee (on the design team) and his comment can be considered official.